# Application of a property about nilpotent group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

There is a quite fundamental theorem about the nilpotent groups that if $Z_1 \leq Z_2 \leq \cdots \leq Z_m=G$ is the upper central series of $G$ and suppose that $Z(G)$ has finite exponent dividing $e$, then so does $Z_i/Z_{i-1}$.

Does it follows from here that $G/Z(G)$ also has finite exponent dividing $e$.

I am thinking a potential argument using 
$G/Z_{i} \cong (G/Z_{i-1})/ (Z_i/Z_{i-1})$ inductively. Is this feasible?

Comment: What you seem to have writte  is *not* the lower but rather the upper central series.

Comment: yes! thank you!

Comment: In the dihedral group of order $16$, $Z(G)$ has order $2$ but $G/Z(G)$ is dihedral of order $8$ and has exponent $4$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following group: 
$$ 
G=
\begin{Bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & * & * & \cdots & *\\
 & 1 & * &\cdots & *\\
 &  & \ddots &\cdots & *\\
 &  &  &  & 1
\end{bmatrix}_{n\times n}\colon *\in\mathbb{Z}_p
\end{Bmatrix}.$$
The upper central series is interesting for this group:
$$1 \leq 
\begin{Bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & \cdots  & 0 & *\\
 & 1 & \cdots  & 0 & 0\\
 &  & \ddots &\cdots & 0\\
 &  &  &  & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{Bmatrix} \leq 
\begin{Bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \cdots & 0  & * & *\\
 & 1 & \cdots  & 0 & *\\
 &  & \ddots &\cdots & 0\\
 &  &  &  & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{Bmatrix} \leq \cdots 
$$
[fill up anti-diagonals from right corner successively].

Each section $Z_i/Z_{i-1}$ is elementary abelian $p$-group, but you can arbitrarily increase the exponent by increasing the size of matrices.